# com.google.api.client.extensions.java6 cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I'm trying to follow the tutorials for using google calendar api in here 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

I tried it in eclipse but I have errors in

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

> The import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6 cannot be resolved

where it says they cannot be resolved and a

> The declared package "" does not match the expected package
>   "main.java"

in the first line

I think the problem lies in the structure of my files but I have no idea how to structure it , I installed gradle plugin as pre-requisite of using google calendar api stated in the link but I'm not sure how to add in build.gradle so I just add a new file and name it build.gradle

[image]

Comment: Try to unzip the zip file(assume that contains the jar files you need) and add the jars to the classpath.

Comment: After I unzipped it and added it using add external jars the errors turn from red to grey , but the error description is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing JDK compliance to 1.7 in project properties > java compiler